# What version of Gradle plugin do I use in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have the following `build.gradle` in my Android app:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0"
}
```

and get a warining:

```
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.0.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 31

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
```

But when I try to use Gradle plugin 7.4 I get this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.
    Searched in the following locations:
    - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4/gradle-7.4.pom
    - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4/gradle-7.4.pom
    Required by:
        project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

with 7.2 I get this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\dev\repos\examples\src\LinesGame\build-LinesGameQt-Android_Qt_6_4_0_x86_64_debug_Clang_x86_64-Debug\android-build\build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-build'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.4. Current version is 7.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\dev\repos\examples\src\LinesGame\build-LinesGameQt-Android_Qt_6_4_0_x86_64_debug_Clang_x86_64-Debug\android-build\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-7.4-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

What is happening?

**EDIT1**

If I spefify 7.3.1 version in `build.gradle` I get the following strange error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\dev\repos\examples\src\LinesGame\build-LinesGameQt-Android_Qt_6_4_0_x86_64_debug_Clang_x86_64-Debug\android-build\build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-build'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.4. Current version is 7.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\dev\repos\examples\src\LinesGame\build-LinesGameQt-Android_Qt_6_4_0_x86_64_debug_Clang_x86_64-Debug\android-build\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-7.4-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

What can it be?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend messing with gradle plugin version. Simply click upgrade when the IDE prompt you to do so and let the IDE do the rest.

Comment: @RickyMo My IDE is QT Creator, it does not update it.

Comment: When you are using gradle 7.4.1, the error you're getting is that you can't find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.   My search of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/7.4.0 shows that it exists.  The error you're getting means that the repositories that your build searched did not contain that artifact.  The repository that I see it in has the date 1/23/2023 for that artifact, so it might be a timing thing, or that you need to add a repository that does contain that artifact.

Comment: The second error is advising you the you must use Gradle version 7.4.  The fact that you're using gradle 7.3.1 but it says you're using 7.2 is somewhat misleading.  It still means the 7.3.1 in not compatible.  The compatibility check is being none by Android.  I believe its the AGP.  The check by the AGP is saying the AGP is requiring gradle 7.4 as the minium gradle version for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 7.4 of the Android Gradle plugin doesn't exist, the latest stable version is `7.3.1`, as you can see in the [Google's Maven repo index](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=gradle#com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1). Other versions you could use are `7.4.0-beta02` and `8.0.0-alpha05`.

Comment: Probably something is wrong with my build environment, but with 7.3.1 I get `Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.4. Current version is 7.2.` error message, see EDIT1

Comment: There's Gradle as the build tool, and there's the Android Gradle plugin, both have separate versioning schemes. For Gradle, you probably want `7.5.1`, which is the latest version (https://gradle.org/releases/). For the Android Gradle plugin, you probably want `7.3.1`.

Comment: `gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` helped